# Does a complete list of open quantum software projects exist?

Tags: resource-request, programming

An answer to 
[Is there any source which tabulates quantum computing algorithms for simulating physical systems?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/is-there-any-source-which-tabulates-quantum-computing-algorithms-for-simulating) mentions the [Quantum Algorithm Zoo](https://math.nist.gov/quantum/zoo/), a list of quantum algorithms. Several answers to [Programming quantum computers for non-physics majors](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/programming-quantum-computers-for-non-physics-majors) include links to different kinds of development kits. Likewise, [What programming languages are available for quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/what-programming-languages-are-available-for-quantum-computers) gathers a couple of good attempts at listing those.

The present question is related to the above, and yet it's not answered by the above resources.

**Does a complete list of open quantum software projects exist?**

Ideal answers would be: if it exists, the link to said list, and if it doesn't, a (well-formatted) as-exhaustive-as-possible compilation of open quantum software projects.

Related question: [Are there any quantum software startups?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/are-there-any-quantum-software-startups)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a really long list of quantum software projects on [Quantiki](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/list-qc-simulators). It's mostly about quantum simulators, quantum compilers and QC programming environments.

But you inspired me to start a curated list of open-source quantum software projects on GitHub [here](https://github.com/markf94/os_quantum_software). It should not be exclusive to the aforementioned categories but list ANY (reasonable) open-source quantum software project out there. I will be doing my best to add as many projects as I can, but it would be great if some of you would contribute!

Comment: This is awesome! I'm passing the information on the person that actually made the request on twitter, I think they will be delighted.

Comment: Beware that one problem with the quantiki list is that it's *too* comprehensive. It's hard to find what you want, and there's quite a few dead projects on there.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on esduran's answer, another great source is the [Quantum Open Source Foundation](https://qosf.org), run the authors of the [same paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09167). It contains a constantly updated list of all open source projects in quantum computation, which ones are active, good learning resources and community channels, as well as evaluations of the bigger software packages.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is still open, I thought I'd share a great paper by professor Pete Wittek titled [*Open Source Software in Quantum Computing*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09167). Dr. Wittek has compiled a list of some open-source quantum computing projects with evaluations based on criteria such as documentation, license, etc. Dr. Wittek also provides a sort of call-to-action to get more people involved in advancing the quantum software stack