# What are some open sources projects on quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate

I am looking to collaborate on open source simulation efforts.

Comment: Anything specific you are looking to work on? Also, what do you feel you add to a collaborative effort?

Comment: What sort of language do you want to program in (or are you interested in some of the more testing and documentation oriented sides of things)? Do you want the project to be a pure simulator or focused on a specific topic? Do you want it to be a big or small project? (Just some questions to get you thinking.)

Comment: I think the OPs curiosity is not yet so detailed. (But it is enough detailed to make the question well-determined and clear.)

Comment: Our business ar-tiste-qb.net has several open source projects and a lot of Latin members. BUT, we do not do AMO. The people who make AMO are the groups dedicated to ion trap hardware

Comment: Also Fujitsu in Japan combine AMO, quantum computing, and software

Comment: @rrtucci I'm afraid that comments on this site need to be in English. I didn't want to lose your contributions, so I translated them. I hope you are fine with the words I've put into your mouth. If not, feel free to delete.

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact a [quantum computing topic tag](https://github.com/topics/quantum-computing) on github which comes up with a list of a whole bunch of projects.

[QISKit](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-core) is pretty well known; it's connected with IBM's quantum experience as well as the QASM language. It's a pure simulator.

In another direction, there's projects like [OpenFermion](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion) which is for finding algorithms to simulate different problems in quantum chemistry.

A fabulous little simulator that I prefer over IBM's is [Quirk](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quirk) which runs in your browser and is open source.

You can also start your own project like [I did](https://github.com/physicsnerd/qc-sim), though I would not recommend becoming an open-source contributor to mine because I haven't updated my repository in a while and I'm pretty sure everything there is rather decisively out of date.

If you can provide some more criteria, I can recommend some more specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some lists of open source quantum projects [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/does-a-complete-list-of-open-quantum-software-projects-exist).

I’d also advise you to check out the [QISKit](https://qiskit.org/) and [Forest](https://www.rigetti.com/community) Slack channels to find some potential ideas and collaborators.