# Are there sites that allow to learn about quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

So, I wanted to learn about quantum computing.

What should I learn and where do I start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be an informative introduction to Quantum?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/what-would-be-an-informative-introduction-to-quantum) and [Are there any organised resources available from where I can begin my quantum computing studies?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/what-would-be-an-informative-introduction-to-quantum)

Comment: Also see: [Does a study guide exist that starts from a “purely CS background” and advances towards “making a new quantum programming language”?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/does-a-study-guide-exist-that-starts-from-a-purely-cs-background-and-advances)