# What are the basics needed to learn quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request

I was very inspired by Michio Kaku's [explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgFVzOksm4o) on the possibilities of quantum computing and also listening to Talia Gershon's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S52rxZG-zi0&t=4s) on it.

As I come from a business & analytics background, what materials can I begin exploring to prepare to learn more about the field of quantum computing? Eg. what would I need to study to understand Peter Shor's algorithm, [Siraj's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGD6KQ6bRS8) on physics, etc.

Comment: the bible of quantum computing is certainly Nielsen, Chuang, *quantum computation and quantum information*. Being already comfortable with linear algebra and Hilbert spaces is preferable, as it will allow you to understand quantum mechanics in general at a deeper level, but the book has an introduction to the subject that should go deep enough for the purpose of computation

Comment: **Related:** [Does a study guide exist that starts from a "purely CS background" and advances towards "making a new quantum programming language"?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1926), [Are there any organised resources available from where I can begin my quantum computing studies?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2082), [Resources for learning quantum computing from an undergraduate physics perspective](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5234) & [What would be an informative introduction to Quantum?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2724).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *General background*:

Quantum computing (theory) is at the intersection of math, physics and computer science. (Experiment also can involve electrical engineering.) Eventually you will want to learn aspects of all of these fields, but when starting you can use any for an entry into the field. Within each field, the subjects you will want to know are:

**Physics:**

> First learn quantum mechanics. At more advanced levels, various
> aspects of quantum information overlap with AMO, condensed matter and
> high energy.

**More**

- [John Preskill's lecture notes](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/#lecture) are slightly more advanced and use a physics perspective.

**Math:**

> First linear algebra and probability. Later my preferences would be to
> learn some group and representation theory, random matrix theory and
> functional analysis, but eventually most fields of math have some
> overlap with quantum information, and other researchers may emphasize
> different areas of math.

**Computer Science:**

> Most theory topics are relevant although are less crucial at first:
> i.e. algorithms, cryptography, information theory, error-correcting
> codes, optimization, complexity, machine learning. If you haven't had
> any CS theory exposure, undergrad algorithms is a good place to start
> because it will show you CS-theory ways of thinking, including ideas
> like asymptotic analysis.

**More:**

- [David Mermin's lecture notes](http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/mermin/qcomp/CS483.html) are elementary and have a CS focus
- [Does a study guide exist that starts from a "purely CS background" and advances towards "making a new quantum programming language"?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/does-a-study-guide-exist-that-starts-from-a-purely-cs-background-and-advances?rq=1)

---

***General quantum computing texts***:

Here is a very partial list of resources for learning more about quantum computing and quantum information.

- The canonical reference for learning quantum computing is the textbook [Quantum computation and quantum information](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&redir_esc=y) by Nielsen and Chuang.
- Another good book (with more of a "little yellow book" experience) is [Classical and Quantum Computation](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0821832298) by Kitaev, Shen and Vyalyi.

---

> If you want to get a flavor of what research is currently hot, then
> one place to look is at the program of the last few QIP workshops. A
> less curated list of interesting papers can be found at [scirate.com](https://scirate.com/) ,
> where looking at the most scited papers in the last year should bring
> up some interesting work.

---

*Specialized sources*:

Some more specialized books/lecture notes are here. These are more modern and in-depth than the general resources above.

- [Quantum Algorithms](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Eamchilds/qa/) lecture notes by Andrew Childs
- [From Classical to Quantum Shannon Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445) by Mark Wilde. Thorough and detailed with plenty of exercises.
- [The Functional Analysis of Quantum Information Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7188) written by Gupta, Mandayam and Sunder based on lectures by Effros, Paulsen, Pisier and Winter. Denser and focused on the math side more than applications.
- [Alice and Bob meet Banach](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Eaubrun/ABMB/index.html) by Aubrun and Szarek. Incomplete textbook draft, but it looks like it'll be the definitive treatment of the probabilistic method in quantum information.
- [The Mathematics of Entanglement](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01790) by Brandao, Christandl, Walter and myself. Idiosyncratic and incomplete lecture notes on some of our pet topics.

**NOTE**:
The above information is based on [this MIT page](http://www.mit.edu/%7Earam/advice/quantum.html).

---

**Other StackExchange Questions.**

- [Are there any organised resources available from where I can begin my quantum computing studies?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/are-there-any-organised-resources-available-from-where-i-can-begin-my-quantum-co?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Programming quantum computers for non-physics majors](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/programming-quantum-computers-for-non-physics-majors?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Credits : @SanchayanDutta

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Please note [our policy](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31) on resource-request questions. You also need to include what the resource contains and a review of the material therein. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @SanchayanDutta for pointing out. I'm too a newbie in this field and cant well explain my answer up to the required level.Initially I tired to comment but while doing so prompted me not to post answers there.

Comment: I've added the text from the page you link, just in case it becomes obsolete in the future.

Comment: Thanks magic_man & SanchayanDutta!!

Comment: "Experiment also can involve electrical engineering" - the risk of the success of associated technology is basically in measurement of quantum states and in that sense EE is crucial; would have expected more than a side note, here.